# Animating alerts with AngularJS instead of jQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I am working on a blog application with **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and **AngularJS v1.7.8**.

The *post comments form* is submitted via AngularJS. Here is the form:

```
<div class="comments-form" ng-controller="PostCommentController">
    <h3>Leave a comment</h3>
    <form name="commentForm" novalidate>
        <div class="row uniform">
            <div class="form-controll 6u 12u$(xsmall)">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" ng-model="newComment.name" placeholder="Name" ng-required="true" />
                <span class="error" ng-show="(commentForm.name.$touched && commentForm.name.$invalid) || (commentForm.$submitted && commentForm.name.$invalid)">This field can not be empty</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-controll 6u$ 12u$(xsmall)">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" ng-model="newComment.email" placeholder="Email" ng-required="true" />
                <span class="error" ng-show="(commentForm.email.$touched && commentForm.email.$invalid) || (commentForm.$submitted && commentForm.email.$invalid)">Enter a valid email address</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-controll 12u$">
                <textarea name="comment" rows="6" id="message" ng-model="newComment.comment" placeholder="Comment" ng-required="true"></textarea>
                <span class="error" ng-show="(commentForm.comment.$touched && commentForm.comment.$invalid) || (commentForm.$submitted && commentForm.comment.$invalid)">This field can not be empty</span>
            </div>

            <!-- Break -->
            <div class="12u$">
                <input type="submit" value="Add comment" ng-click="createComment()" class="button special fit" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="commentSubmitted == true">{{commentSuccessMsg}}</div>
</div>
```

And here is the *AngularJS controller* that manages it's submission to the application's back-end:

```
 // Post comment
.controller('PostCommentController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    const slug = $routeParams.slug;
    $http.get('api/' + slug).then(function(response) {

        let post_id = response.data.post.id;

        $scope.commentSubmitted = false;

        $scope.newComment = {
            slug: slug,
            post_id: post_id,
            name: $scope.name,
            email: $scope.email,
            comment: $scope.comment
        };

        $scope.createComment = function(){
            if ($scope.newComment.name !== undefined && $scope.newComment.email !== undefined && $scope.newComment.comment !== undefined){
                $http.post('api/comments/create/' + post_id, $scope.newComment)
                .then(() => {
                    $scope.newComment = {};
                    $scope.commentForm.$setPristine();
                    $scope.commentForm.$setUntouched();
                    $scope.commentSuccessMsg = "Your comment was submitted. It will be published after aproval";
                    $scope.commentSubmitted = true;
                });
            }
        };
    });
}])
```

I have not been able to find an *AngularJS way* to animate the form alert(s) out of the scene. I have been using jQuery for a long time for frontend animations and with jQuery I would have done something like this:

```
// Hide alerts
$('.alert:not(".alert-dismissible")').each(function(){
 $(this).delay(4000).slideUp(200);
});
```

What would be a simple and robust AngularJS *alternative* to this kind of solution?

Comment: use javascript just to add a class, you can do this with plain js, then use css transition/animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution with CSS `keyframes` and AngularJS's `$timeout`:

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0.01;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.fadeout {
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut 1s;
   animation: fadeOut 1s;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   border: none;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

I have ised AngularJS `$timeout` to `$scope.createComment` for the delay:

```
$scope.createComment = function() {
  if ($scope.newComment.name !== undefined && $scope.newComment.email !== undefined && $scope.newComment.comment !== undefined) {
    $http.post('api/comments/create/' + post_id, $scope.newComment)
      .then(() => {
        $scope.newComment = {};
        $scope.commentForm.$setPristine();
        $scope.commentForm.$setUntouched();
        $scope.commentSuccessMsg = "Your comment was submitted. It will be published after aproval";
        $scope.commentSubmitted = true;
        // this was added for the delay (3 seconds)
        $timeout(function() {
          $scope.fadeout = "fadeout";
        }, 3000);
      });
  }
};
```

The alert div looks like so:

```
<div class="alert alert-success {{fadeout}}" ng-show="commentSubmitted == true">{{commentSuccessMsg}}</div>
```

There is a working demo **[HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G9MFY4KDF7H4)**.

Answer (score -1):

Change the class after the delay, use CSS to animate the slides.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations